# MPMoviePlayerController orientation bug on device but not in simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, mpmovieplayercontroller, screen-orientation

I am getting a weird bug when I load a movie on the iPad device but not in the simulator using MPMoviePlayerController. Works perfect in simulator.
When I load the movie on device it's frame is set incorrectly but when I rotate it sets the frame correctly. The movie is set to play only in landscape mode. If my previous view is in portrait mode it works perfectly by rotating it to landscape but when I am in landscape mode it initially places the x,y coordinates wrongly on device.

Answer (score 1):

There are several bugs -- especially UI bugs -- in the simulator that cause it to not behave as the devices does.  In addition, there are timing issues (your computer is almost certainly faster than an iOS device) memory issues can be masked (your computer has more RAM), etc.

This is why the simulator is good for initial testing, but all software should be tested on the device before being shipped.